# Javascript syntax highlighter for Objective C

Tags: javascript, iphone, objective-c, ios

I am using google prettify, but it seems to not highlight objective-c code.

Does anyone know of a javascript highlighter that supports code highlighting of objective-c? (so that I can highlight objective c code on an HTML page using javascript)

Comment: You might want to edit your question. Right now, it's not clear if you want to highlight Objective-C code in a web page with JavaScript or if you want to highlight JavaScript code on an iPhone. Just a heads up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at [this page which lists some brushes](http://www.undermyhat.org/blog/2009/09/list-of-brushes-syntaxhighligher/), including Objective-C, for [SyntaxHighlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/)

Answer (score 3):

http://www.dreamingwish.com/dream-2011/objc-brush-for-syntax-highlighter-mt.html
this brush support the same highlight color as xcode